# How to externalize JSON

Tags: python, json

I have the following `JSON` in my view (simplified for this example):

```
video = 
     {
     'label': 'hd',
     'url': 'google',
     'format': 'mp4',
     'video_codec': 'h264',
     'audio_codec': 'aac',
     'size': '1080x720',
     }
```

And I can call a function like so: do_something(video)

However, when I try and extract this `JSON` into an external file, as follows --

```
file=open('data.json')
video=file.read()
```

I get an error, which appears to be related to having newlines and excessive spaces in the file. How would I 1) format the above json document to put it into an external file; and 2) how would I import it so I can use it with a function? Thank you.

Comment: Arggh!  Single quotes is not legal JSON!

Comment: is that first code block the contents of the file, or is there something else?  Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: JSOn is not a python dictionary, you can't have the last comma either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy once you have actual JSON, preferably from [`json.dump()`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dump).

```
$ cat t.json
{
  "label": "hd",
  "url": "google",
  "format": "mp4",
  "video_codec": "h264",
  "audio_codec": "aac",
  "size": "1080x720"
}
$ python << EOF
> import json
> f = open('t.json')
> print json.load(f)
> f.close()
> EOF
{u'format': u'mp4', u'url': u'google', u'label': u'hd', u'audio_codec': u'aac', u'video_codec': u'h264', u'size': u'1080x720'}
```